# Merge two data frames with left join With No Intersection

Tags: r

Hello guys So I want to merge two data frames dt1, dt2

by="email" but with no intersection!

Comment: Why not to subtract merge(dt1,dt2,all=FALSE) from merge(dt1,dt2,all=TRUE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no intersection then columns from not matching data frames will be empty hence it will be more informative to have two outputs. Hope this helps.

```
library(dplyr)
not_matching_dt1 <- anti_join(dt2,dt1, by="email")
not_matching_dt2 <- anti_join(dt1,dt2, by="email")
```

Comment: Hey so my  length(dt2$email) had 2136 rows
after the anti join -> 1819
So it means the dt1 had 317 same rows by email?

The length(dt1$email) had 576
after the anti join -> 259
Same as for dt2?

Comment: In the first part of your question, `length(dt2$email)` =2136 rows and 1819 has no matching values in dt1 same for part 2 of your question, out of 576, there are 259 rows has no matching values in dt2

Comment: Oh great thank you that was infrorming! I have so much data I just cant start counting and validating on my own!

Comment: Can I contact you somewhere else? Because I have something that I need to understand and I think it will take much time if I ask it here? It has to do about matrixes and R. Thank you